# What is the equivalent to df.to_markdown() for a Polars Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

In Pandas, it is super easy to just do

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

display(Markdown(my_df.to_markdown()))
```

In a Notebook to get nice-looking tables printed out.

if you have a Polars dataframe, you (obviously) get

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_markdown'

My current workaround is to

```
to_display = my_df.to_pandas()
display(Markdown(to_display.to_markdown()))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the config set_tbl_formatting option

e.g.

```py
In [5]: with pl.Config() as cfg:
   ...:     cfg.set_tbl_formatting('ASCII_MARKDOWN')
   ...:     display(Markdown(repr(df)))
   ...:
shape: (2, 3)
| abc  | mno   | xyz   |
| ---  | ---   | ---   |
| f64  | str   | bool  |
|------|-------|-------|
| -2.5 | hello | true  |
| 5.0  | world | false |
```

See https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_formatting.html for more options

Comment: I tried that, but how do I direct the print output so that the notebook renders the markdown?
display(Markdown(print(df))) does not do that.

Comment: just `display(df)`

Comment: display(df) displays it "natively" and not as a Markdown render of the dataframe.

Comment: ah might be `display(Markdown(repr(df)))` then?

Comment: Look at the example of https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_formatting.html

Comment: display(Markdown(repr(df))) is close, but the displayed table gets truncated.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I believe this is what we are trying here. Am I missing some part of it?

Comment: @Fontanka16 the extra options fed to config might help.

Comment: Can also do `with pl.Config(tbl_formatting="ASCII_MARKDOWN") as cfg:`; all `cfg.set_foo(bar)` methods can be passed as `Config(foo=bar)`. (Useful for passing around a dict of options repeatedly.)

Comment: @Fontanka16 You can use `cfg.set_tbl_rows(-1)` and `cfg.set_tbl_cols(-1)` to display all rows and columns, respectively.